# Erro de implementação de interface no WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

Estou fazendo um exemplo usando WCF é me gerou um erro e não estou conseguindo descobrir o que poderia está errado.

Mensagem de erro:

> WCFService.Service1 does not implement interface member
>   WCFService.IService1.BuscarPessoas().
>   WCFService.Service1.BuscarPessoas() cannot implement
>   WCFService.IService1.BuscarPessoas()   because it does not have the
>   matching return type of WCFService.pessoa.

Código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WCFService
{
    [DataContract]
    public class pessoa
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string SobreNome { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Idade { get; set; }

    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WCFService
{

    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        pessoa BuscarPessoas();

        [OperationContract]
        pessoa BuscarPessoaPorIdade(int idade);
    }

}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WCFService
{
  name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {

        private List<pessoa> CriarListaPessoas()
        {

            List<pessoa> listaPessoas = new List<pessoa>()
            {
                new pessoa(){Nome="Caludia", SobreNome="Borges",Idade=25},
                new pessoa(){Nome="Jose", SobreNome="Borges",Idade=25},
                new pessoa(){Nome="Marços", SobreNome="Borges",Idade=25},
                new pessoa(){Nome="paulo", SobreNome="Borges",Idade=25},
                new pessoa(){Nome="Maria", SobreNome="Borges",Idade=25},
                new pessoa(){Nome="Marlon", SobreNome="Borges",Idade=25},
            };

            return listaPessoas;
        }


        public List<pessoa> BuscarPessoas()
        {
            return CriarListaPessoas();
        }

        public pessoa BuscarPessoaPorIdade(int idade)
        {
            return CriarListaPessoas().Find(pResult => pResult.Idade == idade);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você define na `interface` que o método `BuscarPessoas` deve retornar o tipo `pessoa` mas na implementação está a retornar `List<pessoa>`

Você deve de alterar a interface para:

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<pessoa> BuscarPessoas();

    [OperationContract]
    pessoa BuscarPessoaPorIdade(int idade);
}
```

Comment: ramaral,deu certo muito grato pela ajuda.